# Decrease value in inputs - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an input whose value is 4 or it can be any one and when I press the button it is generating another dynamic input, **what I need is that each time a dynamic input is generated the value of each input is subtracted by -1 until it is in 1.**

I have not been able to make it work as I need it, if someone can help me I would be very grateful, I have reviewed several examples but I have not been able to make it work, any help is welcome.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const defaultState = {
  nombre: 4
  
};

function Row({ onChange, onRemove, nombre }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={nombre}
        onChange={e => onChange("nombre", e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Decrementar"
      />
      
      <button onClick={onRemove}>Eliminar</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default function Pruebas() {

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([defaultState]);
  
  const handleOnChange = (index, name, value) => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows[index] = {
      ...copyRows[index],
      [name]: value
    };
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  const handleOnAdd = () => {
    setRows(rows.concat(defaultState));
    
  };

  const handleOnRemove = index => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows.splice(index, 1);
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Row
          {...row}
          onChange={(name, value) => handleOnChange(index, name, value)}
          onRemove={() => handleOnRemove(index)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleOnAdd}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate a new row make sure to decrement the field `nombre`'s value see for a full example : https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-over-inc-3nixd

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but how do I do so that when it decreases to 1, it does not stop regressing more?

Comment: I tried the answer and there is an inconvenience when the first dynamic input is generated, -1 is subtracted until there it goes well but when another dynamic input is generated the value does not continue to subtract.

Comment: it shows me an error when I put it in:  const [defaultState, setDefaultState] = useState({nombre:4});

Comment: You need to remove const defaultState = {
  nombre: 4
  
};

Comment: I already deleted it but the error remains

Comment: And if the value was not 4, if not that is the value that one has placed in the input, how would it be?

Comment: I'll make a sandbox example for you :D

Comment: ready I remain pending

Comment: @Giovanny sorry bro, I updated the answer and added  a link to the example

Comment: check but it does nothing it just loads new fields of inputs but.

Comment: I did not add the body of handleOnChange I left it empty as I did not understand what you are trying to do with it

Comment: The idea is simply to place a number in the first input and to decrease the values ​​of each dynamic input until the last input is 1

Comment: example : https://i.ibb.co/F3HTvsB/ejemplo.png ,  when you click the button each time - you must start to decrease -1 until reaching 1

Comment: Check the example now ( I hope this is what you are looking for )

Comment: I already saw the update and there is only one detail when the inputs start to be generated at the top there is an input showing the sequence that follows, I send you an example : https://i.ibb.co/ynPCq8z/secuencia.png

Comment: Yes because the input value is bonded to nombre, now after you enter a number the input value will be re-seted after 1s

Comment: Thank you very much I serve myself, I have another question a bit similar to this one, I do not know if you could help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325397/select-dynamics-reactjs

Comment: @Giovanny I left an answer on  that question :)

Comment: hello good and check the answer, what I need is that the same algorithm that I have works the same but with a button in each select as I comment in the question

Comment: hello, What I need is that it works as in the example that I send you but when the add buttons appear that when clicking it generates the other dynamic select and not that the select is generated automatically, the only select that is generated automatically is the first one where it is not the add button appears. https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-babbage-e8fb2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello Zouhair Dre, I have a problem with the exercise that I solve, I need the inputs to load independently, I am going to send you the problem I have at the moment, thank you :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365050/stacked-dynamic-inputs-reactjs