# select dynamics - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an input that generates dynamic select, when placing a value in the input this dynamically adds a select with those amounts of values, for example if the value in the input is 4 in the select it loads me the numbers from 1 to 4 and if I select a value in that select, for example, 2 loads me another select with the numbers from 3 to 4 and so on until reaching the value of 4, it also has a condition that if the highest number is chosen in the first select It would be 4 in this example, it does not generate any additional statements.

**Now what I need is that the statements are not generated automatically, as it is doing, is that there is a button for each select and when giving it there is if it generates the other select.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dawn-c55ux?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I would add a button from `onClick` right next to the generated select.

Instead of putting a function on `onChange`, put it on this new button on `onClick`.

Comment: if it is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you initialize the max number in the input then the first Select will be generated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-select-forked-qn212?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what I need is that the same algorithm that I have works the same but with a button in each select as I comment in the question..

Comment: Do you mean next to each select there is a button that allows you to create another select ? ( if that is the case, I already added this to the example).

Comment: What I need is that it works as in the example that I send you but when the add buttons appear that when clicking it generates the other dynamic select and not that the select is generated automatically, the only select that is generated automatically is the first one where it is not the add button appears. 
  https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-babbage-e8fb2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you can help me, I will order you...