# Stacked dynamic inputs - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an input and a select starting when placing any value in the case of the input, it begins to generate dynamic statements and in the case of the input, dynamic inputs are generated but in decrement, everything works fine, I only need that the dynamic inputs that begin to appear are show one by one and not all piled up as I show in the picture.

Problem screenshot:

[image]

This is I would like it to be:

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

//input dynamic
import Row from "./Row2";

let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};

function Pruebas(props) {

  /*input dynamic */
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [initialeRow, setInitialRow] = useState({ nombre: "" });
  
  const handleOnChange = (index, value) => {
    const copy = rows.map((e, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        e.nombre = value;
      }
      return e;
    });
    setRows([...copy]);
  };
  
  const handleOnAdd = () => {
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre - 1 });
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  };

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  const [input_multi, setInput_multi] = useState();

  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }

    //input dynamic
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre - 1 });
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  };

  //input dynamic
  const handleInput_division = (event) => {
      
    setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
  };


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row">
          <label>PHASES</label>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h6>enter a number</h6>
            <div class="input-group ">
              <input
                type="number"
                name="numberIni"
                placeholder="0"
                class="form-control"
                value={input_multi}
                onChange={(event) => setInput_multi(event.target.value)}
              />

              <br />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">  <i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
              <br />
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <h6>2 - # input dynamic</h6>

                              <div class="input-group ">
                            <select name='numberIni2' class='form-control' onChange={handleInput_division}>
                                   <option value='no' selected>
                                       Seleccione </option>
                                   <option value='2'> 2</option>
                                   <option value='3'>3
                                   </option>
                                   
                                </select>
                       
                       <br/>
                           
                      
                            </div>
                            </div>
            </div>

            
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
      <div class="col-sm-12 btn btn-primary">
        <b>PHASES</b>
      </div>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {numberIni && (
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  1° PHASES <br />
                  select a number :&nbsp;{" "}
                </font>
              </label>
              <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
                <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                  .fill(1)
                  .map((value, key) => {
                    return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1} equipment</option>;
                  })}
              </select>
              <label>
                <font size="2">&nbsp;equipment </font>{" "}
              </label>

              {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                .fill(1)
                .map((value, key2) => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      {arraySelect[key2] && (
                        <>
                          <label>
                            <font size="2">
                              2° select another number <br />
                              classify: &nbsp;{" "}
                            </font>{" "}
                          </label>
                          <select
                            onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                            name=""
                            id=""
                          >
                            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>

                            {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                              return (
                                <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                                  {arraySelect[key2][key3]} equipment
                                </option>
                              );
                            })}


                          </select>

                          {rows.map((e, index) => (
        <Row
          nombre={e.nombre}
          index={index}
          onChange={(index, value) => handleOnChange(index, value)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
                          
                         
                        </>

                      )}

                      
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {numberIni && (
        <input
          onClick={() => resetForm()}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-danger"
          value="restart phase"
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pruebas;
```

//Row2

```js
const Row = (props) => {
    const { onChange, onRemove, nombre, index } = props;
    console.log(props);
    return (
      <div>
        <input
        disabled
          value={nombre}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(index, e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Decrementar"
        />

      </div>
    );
  };
  export default Row;
```

Comment: someone who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by one by one, loading a new input when the old one's value has been changed or just waiting a certain duration before rendering the next input ?

Comment: If "it means one by one, load a new entry when the previous value has been changed", that is, every time a select is generated like this in the code, an input is generated one by one with the decrement as in example from image.

Comment: So you are saying, that if the user select 3, from the first select, a input with the value 3 must be created in addition to the new select ?

Comment: At this moment the select is creating the correct values ​​and the inputs as well but the problem is that the dynamic inputs are repeating each time a select is created, what I need is that only one input appears decreasing for each select like this the picture.

Comment: I am pending, thank you very much..

Comment: hello, can you finally help me?

Comment: I did not fully get what you want to do, it is better if you write things in a better way, for example, simple one-line sentences.

Comment: hello, what I need is that the inputs are decremented one by one each time a select is selected and not all on the stack as is happening in the image one that sends.

Comment: yes it is clear?

Comment: hello zouhair dre,  improve the query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436934/descendant-input-values-reactjs