# descendant input values - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have an algorithm that generates dynamic select and dynamic input, but now I need the dynamic input that is being created to load in a descending way until the value I put in the first select reaches 1 and I am getting an error "undefined Equipment"

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-babbage-e8fb2?file=/src/App.js

error "" undefined Equipment " :
[image]

**how should it be:**

[image]

Comment: use initialeRow.nombre instead of just nombre. Nombre property is defined inside initial row object

Comment: but how would it look in the code?